# Is there a Jackson annotation that converts from String to boolean

Tags: annotations, jackson

this is such a common task I'm hoping to just slap an annotation on my object and call it good.

I'd rather not create custom serializer/deserializer classes etc

Looking at the 1.9 annotations and 2x annotations I don't see one.

Is there a simple Jackson annotation that will convert String to boolean?

Comment: It would be great if you can give an example. Ideally, having a boolean variable in POJO should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "converts from String to boolean"? What kind of class and JSON?

Jackson does implicit conversion as necessary, so that even if JSON has String values (of "true" and "false"), they are converted. Reverse is not done -- native Java booleans come out as JSON booleans.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific precisely to Jackson, but there is a converter in Spring (if that's the environment in which you are using Jackson) `org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToBooleanConverter` which appears to have support for converting the following values to booleans:

```
trueValues.add("true");
trueValues.add("on");
trueValues.add("yes");
trueValues.add("1");

falseValues.add("false");
falseValues.add("off");
falseValues.add("no");
falseValues.add("0");
```